# CloudKit/iCloud - Teacher/Student Scenario

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, cloudkit

I'm a new iOS programmer and I've generally been working using CoreData in iCloud for persistent storage. My newest project will involve this scenario, and I'm not sure how to accomplish it (or if iCloud/CloudKit is able to accomplish it):

Let's say we have an education program for Instructors and Students. Students log their hours of attendance and basic course data.

*Is there any way with CloudKit to be able to attribute the student's data to the instructor as well*? Essentially allowing instructors not to have to log the data since students have already entered it?

Or vice versa?

I understand how this would work in a traditional relational database but I'm not sure if CloudKit has any limitation on this. I'm pretty sure iCloud isn't going to do it... Any recommendations appreciated!

Thanks,
Charlie

**UPDATE**

One of the primary concerns is that instructors will need to be able to bring this data up on their own device. I am thinking instructors will need to validate the student log entry before signing off on the record. After sign off, the record will be attributed to the instructor. Then, I am hoping instructors will be able to open their app to see pertinent instructor totals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work very well. Think as CloudKit as a central database. Who can access what data can be arranged with your data model and queries. Like a regular database you will probably have the recordTypes: Instructors, Students, Courses, StudensInCourses and Attendance.

Comment: In my case, the instructors have an iOS device themselves - what is confusing me is how to attribute in the STUDENTS private database the identifier (appleID im guessing?) for the instructor to be able to access values from the students DB. Or am I thinking of this incorrectly?

Comment: I think you have to create a mechanism where you can make someone an Instructor. Then there will be an Instructor record that is linked to his apple ID. Then that instructor should be able to create  a course and add the students that will attend that course. A student can the query the courses that he is enrolled in and he is allowed to create attendance records.

Comment: O, all the data that must be read by others need to be in the public database. In your case I think all data will be in the public database. Your queries will take care of what can be seen by who.

Comment: And the student would be able to query across all enrolled courses for values - just as a teacher would be able to query across all instructed courses for values as well... correct?

Comment: Does having all the data in the public database create any risks in terms of unauthorized access / editing from outside of my app?

Comment: not really, only your app is allowed to query that container and your are in charge of the queries that will be executed. Of course there is an option that you create the wrong query and data is read that should not be available.

Comment: You have been very helpful, thanks so much for confirming basic questions for me :) Now I will do some digging about CloudKit since I know it isn't a waste of time!

Comment: I have a simple cloudKit quesions I've posted in another topic. I want to use the EVCloudKitDao git, but I'm trying to make sure I understand the basics first. The link is here if you get a chance to look at it. There are no replies yet and you seem to be by far the most helpful expert! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355278/cloudkit-ckqueryoperation-with-dependency

Comment: I have answerd the question.

Comment: For beginners like me, people like you are more than heroes. Thanks so much.